# Unity aab not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, 64-bit, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I have a Unity project that I'm switching from APKs to AABs (app bundles).  Previously, when I was building it as an APK, the Google Play Console told me the APK was 64-bit compliant.

Now that I'm building an aab, I'm getting the warning:

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
>   The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
>   they only have 32-bit native code

1. I have both ARM7 and ARM64 architectures set.
2. I am excluding x86.
3. When I open the .aab in an archive viewer, the lib folder has all of
   the .so's for both arm64-v8a and armabi-v7a.
4. I'm using IL2CPP, .NET 4.x
5. I'm using Unity 2018.3.7f1
6. My ndk version is 16b
7. My 
   Android Studio is up to 3.4.2 and gradle is 3.2

A lot of similar threads here talk about following the "Learn more" links, which I've done.  I had already done all of the work to get my app 64-bit compliant before switching to app bundles.

Other threads talk about Android Studio solutions, which I can't use because my automated build process involves building with Unity from command line, so it has to be Unity configurations or bust.

My expectation was the app bundles were supposed to be the hot new way to let Google build better APKs for you, but it seems like it's getting confused on whether or not aabs are actually 64-bit compliant, which seems to defeat the whole purpose.

Is this a Unity problem, does Google have an error in their system with regards to app bundles, or is there some other step I'm missing?

Comment: It's also worth noting that after waiting an hour, I was finally able to pull the app down from the internal test track onto my phone via Google play and run it.  I'm using a 64 bit device.  (For the first hour trying to pull it down was throwing some kind of generic failure to download error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that there was a bug in the Play Console where this message was displayed even when the AAB was compliant. This should have been fixed last Friday afternoon.
Try again now.

Comment: Okay this morning, after logging out and back into the console it updated and no longer says I'm not compliant.  For the record, leaving the page and navigating back did not refresh it, only re-logging.

But indeed, it looks like Google fixed the bug.  Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue, but the message still appears despite having followed the instructions from Google. Tried to re-logging but it didn't help :s

Comment: This is a long shot, but Jeryl were you able to fix the issue? We are running into this error now despite our app supporting 64bit architecture. Have a support email thread with Google going but they are not very helpful so far.

Answer (score 19):

For those who have this problem since yesterday (August 19, 2019):

In **Player Settings** > **Other Settings** you must now uncheck the **x86** box *(It is for the 32-bit Intel architecture)*.

[image]

---

You will now only have the following warning:

> The device types on which your application can be installed will be more restricted.

But, in my case, it drops from 12392 devices to 12385 devices.

[Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/successful-unity-aab-build-not-compliant-with-the-google-play-64-bit-requirement.729035/#post-4873088) is the opinion of a Unity member on the issue:

> x86 is used by less than 0.4% of all Android devices, so it shouldn't have any real impact.
>
> x86 target will be removed completely in Unity 2019.3.

Comment: almost all x86 android devices have a 'fallback' for armv7, so they can still use the apks, they might be a bit slower though

Comment: For the record, as mentioned in my post, I was already not including x86 in my build.  So this repsonse, at least, wasn't directly related to what I was experiencing.  But it is still useful info.

Comment: Is there another option so that I can still make x86 builds and release them with ARM builds?