# Google play showing this app is not compatible with this version

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I build android apk using `unity` (2019.1.0f2 (64-bit)) and upload on Google Play store, after publishing I figured out my app is not compatible with any device showing on Google Play console.
Before publishing it, I have tested the same apk on several android devices and it works fine. Kindly guide me how to solve this issue. Screenshot from google play is given below:

[image]
 After publish on different android device
[image]

My Manifest file:

[image]

Unity build Settings Snapshot
[image]

Comment: Have you received any email on your play store console registered email id about this issue. try to read these policy : https://source.android.com/compatibility/, https://source.android.com/compatibility/overview

Comment: Can you share a snapshoot of your Android build settings?

Comment: No. Just see notification on developer console your app is live now. @RahulKhatri

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57582318/1860868